# twitter followers image24X24

Tags: twitter

**How can I retrieve the twitters followers image size of 24X24.**

Comment: what language are you trying to hit the twitter api from?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean save the image on your HD ?
I think just right click on it and "save image as" !

Comment: on boss i want to retrieve the list of followers image the size (24X24) not the 48X48 size using php?